# why wont the parent div grow with its children

Tags: html, css

ok so i have a  page with a wrapper div and divs in side. the wrapper is centered(margin auto)and the children are floating left the problem is the wrapper wont grow with its children.
html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="banner"></div>
<h1>Resource page</h1>
<div id="non-vidCon">
    <div id="images" class="debug">
            <ul id="imgList">
                <li>ha</li>
                <li>ha</li>
                <li>ha</li>
                <li>ha</li>
                <li>ha</li>
                <li>ha</li>
                <li>ha</li>
                <li>ha</li>
                <li>ha</li>
                <li>ha</li>
            </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="docs">
            <ul id="docList">
                <li>ha</li>
                <li>ha</li>
                <li>ha</li>
                <li>ha</li>
                <li>ha</li>
                <li>ha</li>
                <li>ha</li>
                <li>ha</li>
                <li>ha</li>
                <li>ha</li>
            </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="vidCon"></div>
```

css:

```
#wrapper {
background-color:#F5F5F5;
width:1000px;
height:100%;
margin: auto;
margin-top: 20px;
position: relative;
}

#banner {
background: url('../images/Duke_BackToBack_Header.jpg');
width: 1000px;
height: 111px;
position: relative;
top: 0px;

}

#non-vidCon {
width: 1000px;
height: auto;
min-height: 300px;
position: relative;
border-top: 1px solid #cccccc;
}

#images {
width: 498px;
height:auto;
position: relative;
float: left;
content: "";


}


#docs {
width: 498px;
height:auto;
position: relative;

content: "";
float: left;


}
```

i've searched through the stack (this site) and have applied some of the fixes, but none worked (inline-block killed my margin auto)any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to clear your floats.

Before the close of `#wrapper`, add:

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.clear {
   clear:both   
}
```

Comment: this may be asking too much, but could you tell me why this worked? for some reason i find pure coding (javascript, action script,java etc...) far easier than css. to me css seems very illogical :P

Comment: I don't think I can say it better than this: http://css-tricks.com/the-how-and-why-of-clearing-floats/

Answer (score 3):

Stick `overflow:auto` on your #wrapper's css, so that it contains the content within it.  You were basically there, just needed a way to wrap that list.

```
#wrapper {
  background-color:#F5F5F5;
  width:1000px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Eas7T/) for an example.  Here's a [jsFiddle example with your old HTML too](http://jsfiddle.net/vCvwU/).

Answer (score 1):

By floating each child of `#non-vidCon`, you're removing all its content from the flow, thus no height for it, no visible background and no care for the length of its content: it's not part of the flow anymore.

Diodeus solution is the most compatible one but needs an extra div. Another solution is adding

```
#non-vidCon:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
```

and only for IE6/7 giving the hasLayout to the element.

```
   #non-vidCon { zoom: 1; }
```